# Delete old record and insert new ones in one query mysql

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to delete old records from table and to insert new ones in one query with mysql?

For example to make this 2 querys into one.

```
DELETE FROM A where customer_id = 5;

INSERT INTO A (product_id, customer_id) VALUES (1, 5);
INSERT INTO A (product_id, customer_id) VALUES (5, 5);
INSERT INTO A (product_id, customer_id) VALUES (12, 5);
INSERT INTO A (product_id, customer_id) VALUES (543, 5);
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I dont want to keep old records only the newest ones

Comment: Maybe you should consider on using update?

Comment: How can I use update if I dont know how much records I have now and how much I want to insert.

Comment: create a `function` in `mysql` : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-function.html

Answer (score 0):

Delete and insert are not meant to be in one single query. However, you can merge your inserts into a single query. This would be the script:

```
DELETE FROM A where customer_id = 5;

INSERT INTO A (product_id, customer_id) VALUES (1, 5), (5, 5), (12, 5), (543, 5);
```